# Sample over a matrix

Tags: sampling

Assume I have a matrix.

```
mat = {{1, 1, 8, 3, 5}, {2, 2, 6, 5, 3}, {3, 3, 9, 2, 7}, {4, 4, 7, 1,
     7}, {5, 5, 3, 6, 8}, {6, 6, 8, 7, 7}, {7, 7, 2, 4, 4}, {8, 8, 9, 
    1, 6}, {9, 9, 1, 1, 2}, {10, 10, 2, 1, 6}, {11, 11, 6, 2, 4}, {12,
     12, 9, 2, 1}};
```

I would like to create new matrix that has dimension $12\times3$.

First 2 column is fixed but 3rd column is randomly selected from last 3 column.

First row would be `{1, 1, 8}` or `{1, 1, 3}` or `{1, 1, 5}`
Second row would be `{2, 2, 6}` or `{2, 2, 5}` or  `{2, 2, 3}`

For example one sample is the following.

```
sem={{{1, 1, 8}, {2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 7}, {4, 4, 7}, {5, 5, 6}, {6, 6, 8}, {7, 7, 2}, {8, 8, 6}, {9, 9, 1}, {10, 10, 6}, {11, 11, 6}, {12,12, 9}}} ;
```

I need say 1000 sample like this. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why give us a matrix and then say "First row could be..."??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Because it wouldn't be nearly as funny if questions would be clearly stated? :)

Comment: ...but waste valuable time and good will...

Comment: Your question is poorly worded. The phrasing of randomly selecting a *column* implies that within each sample, the third column in that sample comes from the same column from the original matrix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a function that does this for exactly one entry. Then use this function on all your entries:

```
rand[{x1_, x2_, rest__}] := {x1, x2, RandomChoice[{rest}]};
rand /@ mat
(* {{1, 1, 8}, {2, 2, 5}, {3, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 1}, {5, 5, 8}, {6, 6,
   7}, {7, 7, 4}, {8, 8, 6}, {9, 9, 1}, {10, 10, 1}, {11, 11, 2}, {12,
   12, 2}} *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Also

```
f0 = Extract[#, {{1}, {2}, {RandomInteger[{3, 5}]}}] &;
f0 /@ mat
```

> {{1, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 2}, {4, 4, 7}, {5, 5, 6}, {6, 6, 7},
>         {7, 7, 4}, {8, 8, 9}, {9, 9, 1}, {10, 10, 1}, {11, 11, 2}, {12, 12, 2}}

And

```
f1 = Transpose@Extract[Transpose@#, {{1}, {2}, {RandomInteger[{3, 5}]}}] &;
f1 @ mat
```

> {{1, 1, 5}, {2, 2, 3}, {3, 3, 7}, {4, 4, 7}, {5, 5, 8}, {6, 6, 7},
>     {7,7, 4}, {8, 8, 6}, {9, 9, 2}, {10, 10, 6}, {11, 11, 4}, {12, 12, 1}}

Answer (score 6):

Here's a faster extractor using a single [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) and single [`RandomInteger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html) call, although still with a minimally expensive [`MapIndexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html) call and a [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html) for reshaping:

```
n = 10000;
mat = RandomInteger[n, {n, n}];

b3extract[mat_] :=
  With[{
    extractSpec =
     Join @@
      MapIndexed[
       Thread[{#2[[1]], {1, 2, #}}] &,
       RandomInteger[{3, Length@mat}, Length@mat]
       ]},
   Partition[
    Extract[mat, extractSpec],
    3
    ]
   ];
```

Here's a timing comparison to the other solutions:

```
b3extract[mat] // RepeatedTiming // First

0.028

(*halirutan imp*)
rand[{x1_, x2_, rest__}] := {x1, x2, RandomChoice[{rest}]};
rand /@ mat // RepeatedTiming // First

10.5

(*kglr imp 1*)

f0 = Extract[#, {{1}, {2}, {RandomInteger[{3, Length@mat}]}}] &;
f0 /@ mat // RepeatedTiming // First

0.597

(*kglr imp 2*)
f1 = Transpose@
    Extract[Transpose@#, {{1}, {2}, {RandomInteger[{3, 5}]}}] &;
f1@mat // RepeatedTiming // First

0.935
```

And here's a correctness check:

```
BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[1];
  b3extract[mat]
  ] ==
 BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[1];
  Extract[#, {{1}, {2}, {RandomInteger[{3, Length@mat}]}}] & /@ mat
  ]

True
```

It also scales surprisingly well (well I guess it's still $~O(n^2)$ or worse but with a good pre-factor, probably from most operations being efficiently dispatched to the kernel):

```
sizes =
  {100, 1000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000};
timings =
 Table[
  With[
   {
    mat = RandomInteger[n, {n, n}]
    },
   b3extract[mat] // RepeatedTiming // First
   ],
  {n, sizes}
  ]

{0.00025, 0.0025, 0.014, 0.030, 0.047, 0.10, 0.22, 0.30, 0.40}


fit =
  NonlinearModelFit[
   Thread[{sizes, timings}],
   prefactor*size^2,
   {prefactor},
   size
   ];
fit["BestFit"]

3.2*10^-10 size^2

ListLinePlot[
 {
  Thread[{sizes, timings}],
  Map[{#, fit["BestFit"] /. size -> #} &, sizes]
  }
 ]
```

[image: asdasd]